# How can I add new web form to cloned app in visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ibm-cloud

How can I add new web form to my web application which I have cloned in visual studio 2015 from IBM Bluemix using Git Repository. I can commit and push the changes I have made in index.html file, but I want to add web form to develop my application. when I try to add a new Item in solution explorer it is not showing option for web form. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with the proper type, then copy all the existing files into the folder and add them. Alternatively, create a new project of the proper type, open up the project file, look for the project type GUID, then open up the original and add/edit the type.

MAKE BACKUPS FIRST.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had already tried to add web forms as an existing item by creating another web site, but it could not reflect on the cloud after commit. how can I look for GUID  please explain the process .

Comment: Open the actual, physical project file in Notepad (or your favorite alternative).